# SublimeText turns into black hole with Unity/nVidia/Xinerama

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg

I recently upgraded to 14.04, and after a little bit of fighting, I got my 4-monitor setup "working".  However, a few applications (I've noticed gedit and SublimeText), will have the entire window blacked out when it loses focus.  Once it's blacked out, I cannot get it to show again without restarting the app.  Just to be clear, this makes the applications unusable.

My setup is using the nVidia proprietary driver version 331.38, on a Quadro NVS-450.  Below is my xorg.conf file, and following that is the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`.  Any ideas what's going on here?

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Below "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E2210H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E2210H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 450"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 450"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "GPU-0.DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, GPU-0.DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "GPU-1.DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, GPU-1.DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

The output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro NVS 450/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 331.38

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It seems it's a memory problem, xinerama makes my two cards to run out of memory with three monitors. Some people managed to solve it increasing shared memory size on the BIOS, unfortunately my cards are not integrated and I don't have that option.

Same problem here, both with Firefox and Thunderbird (and other apps too), focus lost = black window.

Two GeForce 8400 GS with three monitors.

The problem is xinerama with the drivers, since you have to enable Composite manually in the xorg.conf file in order to make unity work.

Going back to nouveau driver solves it, with you get other problems like continuous freezes.

Comment: Did you try reducing the color depth? I just decreased from 24 to 16 to see what happens, and it appears to be a bit more stable.